# Safari translate3d bug with youtube embed videos

Tags: javascript, css, safari, youtube, translate3d

I am trying to make my homepage work with safari iphone/ipad. The thing is, i want to move youtube videos embedded inside `<div>` tags around the page. Normally I do this by using jquery and I just set the offset of the `<div>` tag with the jquery offset method and everything works great, but when i am trying to set the  position with translate3d, than a weird thing happens the  moves correctly to the desired position, but the embedded youtube inside the  doesn't move at all, it stays in the top, left corner of the page.

So basically it seems like I can't move the video with translate3d doesn't matter what i do. It gets weirder if i try to use iframe to embed the youtube video: everything seems to work fine, the video is moving to the correct position, but ZI can't start playing the video by clicking the play button.

```
var youtubeString = ('<object id="video" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/a-sFrDPsmjI?version=3&amp;hl=hu_HU" width="340px" height="200px" wmode="Opaque" allowfullscreen="true"> <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/a-sFrDPsmjI?version=3&amp;hl=hu_HU" wmode="Opaque" allowfullscreen="true"/> </object>');

$(youtubeString).appendTo($myDiv);

var t = "translate3d(" + myPosX + "px, "+ myPosY +"px, 0px)";

$myDiv.css({"-webkit-transform" : wk});
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code and markup that you are trying to use?

Comment: Sounds like the videos use absolute positioning...

Comment: I edited my post added some code, i cant really post the whole thing, because its relativly big, so i just wrote the important parts.

I checked the video positioning, and i tryed to set absolute, inherit and relative positioning in css, and there is no change at all with any of those.

I also playd around with normal css positioning:

$myDiv.css({left: myPosX  "px", top: myPosY "px"});

This one works fine too, but its not supported by safari, so its slow like the offset method, which means i can't use it.

Comment: It looks like you're applying the `wk` variable as the CSS style when `t` has the desired string. [You can try something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/eyBWZ/) but I'm curious to know if that solves the problem.